# Foreign key to a pg_catalog table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to have a foreign key pointing to a field of a system catalog (pg_catalog) table  ?

When I try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT fk_my_table FOREIGN KEY (role_name) REFERENCES pg_roles(rolname) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  referenced relation "pg_roles" is not a table
```

Comment: What's unclear abut the error message? `pg_role` is a view (as the error message indicates and the manual documents)

Comment: No, actually, as clearly stated in the documentation: "PostgreSQL’s
system catalogs are regular tables". pg_roles is a system table within the pg_catalog schema. See: [link]http://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/pdf/9.2/postgresql-9.2-US.pdf

Comment: No, pg_roles is listed under "System views": http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/views-overview.html

Comment: You were right indeed, pg_roles is in "System views", not "System catalogs". Apologies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible.
if you are trying with system table's, u will get the error like

```
  ********** Error **********
    ERROR: permission denied: "pg_attribute" is a system catalog
    SQL state: 42501
```

The system wouldn't enforce the constraint even if you override the permission. 
so we can't create constraint with system table reference.

if u have few roles then go for the manual check or create temp table as from pg_roles then make a constraint.

```
create temp table test1 as select * from pg_roles
```

Comment: Great thanks. Any way to circumvent this ? I have a table with users and I want to make sure they are taken from existing roles.

Comment: for new entry : create trigger and check given roles are existing in the pg_roles, if it is then add the record.